# How to update multiple columns based on condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have this query:

```
UPDATE user
   SET reputation = reputation + 
                    (CASE id WHEN :op   THEN 2 
                             WHEN :user THEN 15 
                     END)
WHERE user in (:user, :op)
```

And I also want to update one more column based on those conditions of that `CASE()` function. Currently I do that by another query:

```
UPDATE user
   SET fee = fee + 
             (CASE id WHEN :op   THEN (SELECT SUM(op_val) FROM money WHERE id = :post_id)
                      WHEN :user THEN (SELECT SUM(user_val) FROM money WHERE id = :post_id)
              END)
WHERE user in (:user, :op)
```

Well as you see the conditions of those two queries above are identical. How can I mix them and make a single query instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query looks strange.  Why would use mix comparisons of `user` and `id` to the input variables.  Do you intend this?

```
UPDATE user
   SET reputation = reputation + 
                    (CASE id WHEN :op   THEN 2 
                             WHEN :user THEN 15 
                     END)
WHERE id in (:user, :op);
```

A `set` clause can set multiple columns:

```
UPDATE user
    SET reputation = reputation + 
                        (CASE user WHEN :op   THEN 2 
                                   WHEN :user THEN 15 
                         END),
        fee = fee + 
             (CASE user WHEN :op   THEN (SELECT SUM(op_val) FROM money WHERE id = :post_id)
                        WHEN :user THEN (SELECT SUM(user_val) FROM money WHERE id = :post_id)
              END)
WHERE user in (:user, :op);
```

You can also write the second condition as:

```
        fee = fee + 
             (SELECT SUM(CASE id WHEN :op THEN op_val ELSE user_val END) FROM money WHERE id = :post_id)
```

Comment: Good eyes .. Thank you .. +1

Comment: Also you have to replace `user` with `id` in your second query *(as you said rightly)*